# Serve i18n translation angular cli gives English text

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-i18n

I've pretty much followed [the official i18n angular guide](https://angular.io/guide/i18n) for translation in angular. However when serving the app with

`g serve --aot --i18nFile=src/locale/messages.fr.xlf --i18nFormat=xlf --locale=fr`

I still get the english text.

I have a messages.xlf and messages.fr.xlf :

**src/messages.xlf**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xliff version="1.2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
  <file source-language="en" datatype="plaintext" original="ng2.template">
    <body>
      <trans-unit id="welcome" datatype="html">
        <source>Hello!</source>
        <context-group purpose="location">
          <context context-type="sourcefile">app/app.component.ts</context>
          <context context-type="linenumber">2</context>
        </context-group>
        <note priority="1" from="description">user welcome</note>
      </trans-unit>
    </body>
  </file>
</xliff>
```

**src/locale/messages.fr.xlf**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xliff version="1.2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
  <file source-language="en" datatype="plaintext" original="ng2.template">
    <body>
      <trans-unit id="welcome" datatype="html">
        <source>Hello!</source>
                <target>Bonjour!</target>
        <context-group purpose="location">
          <context context-type="sourcefile">app/app.component.ts</context>
          <context context-type="linenumber">2</context>
        </context-group>
        <note priority="1" from="description">user welcome</note>
      </trans-unit>
    </body>
  </file>
</xliff>
```

and my template of my test app:

```
<div i18n="user welcome@@welcome">Hello!</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply replace

```
<div i18n="user welcome@@welcome">Hello!</div>
```

By

```
<div i18n="user welcome@@welcome"></div>
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to be it. When doing the above, nothing displays. Furthermore the official doc has the text between the tags.

Comment: Hum, have you regenerated your files ? If your tag has been misplaced, then the translator won't be able to find it. Is it still on line 2 of your file ? You laso have a language=en in your FR file, replace it just to be sure.

Comment: The `source-language="en"` is like that https://angular.io/guide/i18n and represent the source language. Nevertheless it does not work with fr either.

Comment: Is your translated line still on line 2 of your file ? Also, are your files in the right folder ? Could you also try the command `--i18n-file` instead of `--i18nFile`

Comment: same result with `ng serve --aot --i18n-file=./src/locale/messages.fr.xlf --i18n-format=xlf --locale=fr`. Yes it's on line 2.

Comment: Well then, I'm out of solutions. I've searched in 3 of my repositories, each and everyone of them was using all the solutions I offered you (and worked). Sorry I can't be of anymore help :/

Comment: thank you for your time, i'll get back to you when I find the solution

Comment: Well it doesn't work with the official .zip example either, so maybe it's a bug

Comment: Then you should create a ticket for the CLI, tell them the translation isn't working properly. (before that, rapidly check if there's no ticket for that)